# SSJS: Function returns value without return

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, function

I hope someone can help me to understand the following behaviour:

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

    function test(args) {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {}
    }

    Write(Stringify(test([1,2,3,4,5])));
</script>
```

**Output:**

> 5

Why does this return the length of args?
There is no return value for the function. In JS this will result in *undefined*